# Are EU treaties agreed between member states or between member states and the EU?

Tags: european-union, international-relations, treaty

Are EU treaties agreed between member states or between member states and the EU?

Is the EU a sovereign entity in and of itself?

Comment: The EU has been delegated some of the powers of a sovereign country by the member countries. The fundamental treaties are between the members, much of the subsequent day-to-day work includes the EU acting within the scope of their mandate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [read the treaties yourself.](https://europa.eu/european-union/law/treaties_en)

For example in the [Maastricht Treaty](https://europa.eu/european-union/sites/europaeu/files/docs/body/treaty_on_european_union_en.pdf), the treaty is between the "High Contracting Parties", that is the countries themselves. The parties are actually listed as the heads of state of the various countries, and are countersigned by the relevant ministers. For example, the UK's entry:

> HER MAJESTY THE QUEEN OF  THE  UNITED  KINGDOM OF  GREAT BRITAIN AND  NORTHERN IRELAND:
>
> The Rt. Hon. Douglas HURD, Secretary of State for Foreign and Commonwealth Affairs;
>
> The Hon. Francis MAUDE, Financial Secretary to the Treasury